# Deserialize JSON Data from FetchDistributedCacheMap to merge into flow file Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]Extracting Json data from an Attribute variable
I have a flow file that needs to be enriched, So I have created an api that can be called the resulting json is then stored to an attribute and a **DistributedCacheMap** record is then written using **PutDistributedMapCache** to avoid repeated calls to the api for the same device as many flow files arrive.

KV pair looks like this
Key **DeviceName=ABC123**  Value = **{"device":"ABC123","State":"NSW","location":"SYD55"}**

When Flow files are being processed a lookup is done to see if the device data is already in the DistributedMapCache if it is an attribute called cached-value is then assigned using process **FetchDistributedMapCache** the resulting Attribute variable comes back looking like this.
cached-value :{"device":"ABC123","State":"NSW","location":"SYD55"}

What I need to do then is extract the json from the cached-value attribute and merge it back into the flow file to enrich the data within that flow file. I am struggling to find a way to deserialise this json from the **cached-value** attribute to use it back in the flow file. Have tried AttributesToJson without any luck

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Up_One for replying to my question. I ended up solving this in a slightly different way and I thought I would share my answer as someone else may have some ideas to simplify.

I will also share the template I created to try and clarify.

1. Create a flow file to simulate data being received.
   output looks like this, we will enrich the state,rack,location

[image]

2. Extract the device id from the data using EvaluateJsonPath
   [image]
3. Attempt to read the **device** id from the cachemap using FetchDistributedCacheMap and save it to attribute **cached-value**

[image]

result looks like this

[image]

4. I then append the results of the cache read to the end of the flow file using the ReplaceText processor (both are json)
   Properties
   [image]
   Result of append

[image]

5. I then do a second ReplaceText to fix the syntax of the json data after the append operation using the following properties.
   [image]
   The flowfile now looks like this
   [image]
6. I then extract the MetaData variables I plan to use to enrich the original Flow file with **EvaluateJsonPath** processor.

[image]

7. Finally I do a JoltTransform on the flow file data to format the data correctly Properties

[image]

The Data is now formatted in the flow file enriched

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to push the lookup attribute result into you flowfile content, use replacetext processor for this. (replace value should be your lookup attribute result)

After this you need to use an evaluatejsonpath processor to parse the incoming flow content into individual attribute.

AttributesToJson  creates a json payload from flow attributes, you will use it at the end to reconstruct you final json , if you need one.